# how to run pytest Suite from another python program

Tags: python, pytest

I have number of tests defined in a program called test_checks.py. I also have another program called execute.py. test_checks.py contains all checks and execute.py should only execute if all the tests in test_check.py are successful. Is there any way to check that condition and run execute.py by calling test_checks.py from execut.py ?

Comment: Please Give us a sample of your code so that we can improve it

Comment: You can [run pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code) from your code and check the return value - if it is 0 (e.g. success), you can run your code.